# PWM output to adjust voltage

Tags: pwm, varistor

I am trying to create a dimming system for this set of 10 leds, using an output from an ESP32.

This is what I came up with: Using a 20 volt power supply going through a variable resistor which controls the output voltage based on the PWM signal from the ESP32.

[image]

For the variable resistance thing I ordered [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07NWD8W26) from Amazon, but it does not seem to work. I ran the ESP32's PWM from 0% to 100% and my multimeter keeps showing the output voltage jumping from around 0 V to 20 V at around 5%. I'm not sure if am doing something or if the module not output a varied voltage.

If the module is not the correct thing to use would a MOSFET work?

Comment: Your little board contains two mosfets. How did you wire it up?

Comment: Use fixed resistor. Dive into PWM what it exacly does.

Comment: You don't need a 'variable resistor'. You can use the PWM directly to dim the lights.  You'll just need a single transistor controlled by the ESP32, and you can set those LED's to any brightness you want.   N-Channel enhancement mode MOSFET would be ideal.   The LED's would be flashing on/off really fast but your eye THINKS they are dimming (Google "persistence of vision")   Keep the frequency above 60Hz and you shouldn't see objectionable flicker.

Comment: @kartman I wired it up how the amazon site showed it. PWM and gnd on the right and pwr on the left. Ill try the mosfet flicker though. thanks

Comment: Your diagram does not show the board wired that way. You do realise the ‘flicker’ is pwm?

Comment: Looking at the specs for the mosfets on the amazon board tells me it would be marginal at the 3.3V the esp32 provides. And extra transistor and some resistors wiuld solve the problem. Have you Googled a solution? What you want to do is very common and there are many solutions, so why re-invent tge wheel?

Comment: @Kartman I see i didnt know dimming in led can be done with a pwm too. I did google but I wasnt even sure what to look for at first I thought some variables resistor since the voltage is too much to run through the ESP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The module you have purchased does not provide a varying DC as you seem to want.  All it does is to provide a pulse width modulation signal at higher voltage and current than the input PWM.

The module you have uses two MOSFETs.  Yes, you could simply use a MOSFET in place of the module you have.

You don't need a steady DC to power your LEDs.  The pulsing output from the PWM circuit will be fine.

You do have to limit the current through the LEDs, though.

The nine LEDs in series may be too much.  The 2V forward voltage of your LEDs is the nominal voltage.  It may well be higher or lower than that.  If it is a bit higher (say, 2.2V) then the LEDs may not light at all on your 20V power supply.

I'd remove one LED so you only have 8.  That gives you a nominal 16 V for all the LEDs together.

You want 180mA through the LEDs, so you subtract 16 V from 20 V.  That's 4 V difference between power supply and LED forward voltage.  At 180mA, you need a resistor of 22 ohms in series between the power supply and the LEDs.  That will limit the current to a safe value.

Comment: I see so is the chip just a way for the PWM output from the ESP to "step up"? Like increase in voltage and all that? Is the frequency and duty cycle also the same on the output?

Comment: The module (it is **not** a chip) is a way to make high(er) voltage PWM with higher current.

Answer (score 0):

What is the frequency of PWM output? Keeping this higher say 200 Hz will eliminate flicker.

Add a resistor in series with LED string such that when 20 V is connected directly to LEDs, 180 mV runs through the LED. Calculations for R = (Vin-Vled)/ Iled = (20-18)/0.18 = 11 ohms - you may use 10 to 15 ohms approximately. Wattage of resistor >/= 0.5 W. (Calculations for wattage: I * I * R = 0.18 * 0.18 * 11 = 0.36 W)

Answer (score 0):

I think the ground connection can be a problem. Now you have Mosfet connected as high side (drain to Vcc and source to Leds) so the ESP doesnt provide enough voltage to Mosfet gate.

You must connect Mosfet as low side (Source to Gnd and Leds to drain), or use two isolated power supplies that doesnt share common Gnd.